# Send the JS array with ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an array made by function .push . How to send this JS array from this to another php file.Below I have attached the code. The two files are game.js and gallery.php.

Game.js:

```
   imgarray.push({"img_name":img_name,"x":x_value,"y":y_value,"w":w_value,"h":h_value});

        var st = JSON.stringify(imgarray);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "gallery.php",
          data: { data :st},

          success: function(data){
            console.log(st);
            alert("OK");

          }

      });
```

Gallery.php:

```
  <?php
  $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']))[0];
  foreach($data as $d){
  echo($d. '</br>');
  }?>
```

I tried the above code, but I dont know why it produces error. The error I received is Undefined index: data, from the second file (gallery.php).

Can someone help me fix this issue and help me to send the array with ajax to php.

Answer (score -1):

If in your `game.js` you are calling `.push` on an array with a certain object, then the `$_POST['data]` would give you that array. You need to go further inside that array to get to the "push"ed object. Here is how I changed you `game.js`

```
var imgarray = [];
imgarray.push({
    img_name: "myImg",
    x: "x",
    y: "y",
    w: "w",
    h: "h",
});

var st = JSON.stringify(imgarray);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "gallery.php",
    data: { data: st },

    success: function (data) {
    console.log(st);
    alert("OK");
    },
});
}
```

and then your `gallery.php` would change to

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']))[0];
foreach ($data as $d) {
    echo($d. '</br>');
}
```

Comment: This code didnt solve the problem, it still produces the error undefined index: data in gallery.php

Comment: Can you update the code according to my new explanation?

Comment: try this in your gallery.php file 

$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
foreach ($data as $d) {
    foreach($d as $value){
        echo($value);
    }
}

Comment: The problem is the php files prints null value because of undefined index:data. I dont think changing the foreach statement will change it

Comment: What does var_dump($data) print?

Comment: It prints "undefined index: data and NULL"

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the example code that I posted above. https://paste.pics/147acc72bb4fd7d17d2fed8bb66707fa

Comment: Check your console in chrome for any errors. Also, use var_dump() to check what you are getting inside $_POST

Comment: i checked the console and followed excatly your code, but the error still appears. I dont know how to get rid of the undefined index: data, i need to solve that to fix the issue

Comment: What does var_dump($_POST['data']) print?

Comment: var_dump($_POST['data']) produces : "undefined index: data and NULL"

Comment: And what does var_dump($_POST) print?

Comment: var_dump($_POST) prints "array(0) { }"

Comment: Can you inspect the network tab and see what parameters are being passed? Here is how you can do that in chrome. https://datawookie.netlify.app/blog/2016/09/view-post-data-using-chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: The network tab is confusing for me , Also in the response tab it display the error undefined index: data for var_dump($_POST)